# Hikari cp with spring boot.. Active connections always at 1.. Not increasing but not comig down to 0

Tags: java, spring-boot, hikaricp

I am connecting to a db2 database using springBoot application.

I am using SpringBoot 2.1.2 Release.
db2jcc4 version is 4.26.14
At the server startup the database connection is established.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="data.app")
@Bean
public DataSource dataSourceApp(){

return new HikariDataSource(new HikariConfig())
}

@Bean
EntityManagerFactory appEntityManagerFactory(){
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ();
emf.setDataSource(dataSourceApp);
emf.setJPAVendorAdaptor(jpaVendorAdaptor);
emf.afterPropertiesSet();
return emf.getObject();

}


@Bean
publc EntityManager appEntityManager()
{
return appEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}
```

Then this entityManager is used for executing queries for each request.

Following are the connection pool properties

```
data.app.minimumIdle=0
data.app.idleTimeout=120000
data.app.driverClassName=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
data.app.jdbcURL=
data.app.username=
data.app.password=
data.app.maximumPoolSize=10
data.app.connectionTimeout=300000
data.app.poolName=
data.app.maxLifetime=130000
data.app.validationTimeout=300000
```

When the request comes

```
@Autowired
Entitymanager entityManager;

Query query= entitymanager. CreateNativeQuery(queryString) ;

ExecuteQueries(query, queryString)
```

When the application  is first started the active Connections are shown as 0(have enabled Hikari monitoring)
On execution of 1stquery the active connections grow to 1 and remain at 1 even if multiple queries are fired. And even after the idleTimeout and maxlifetime have reached. How do I return back this connection to pool. I have tried using entitymanager.
Close() in the finally block.. But this is also not returning the connection to pool.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the `minimumIdle` property.

From the Hikari docs

> minimumIdle
> This property controls the minimum number of idle connections that HikariCP tries to maintain in the pool. If the idle connections dip below this value and total connections in the pool are less than maximumPoolSize, HikariCP will make a best effort to add additional connections quickly and efficiently. However, for maximum performance and responsiveness to spike demands, we recommend not setting this value and instead allowing HikariCP to act as a fixed size connection pool. Default: same as maximumPoolSize

Ideally for the best performance, you want the min and the max to be the same so connections are created at startup and not created on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have removed minimumIdle from the properties. The problem seems to be in the way i am creating entityManager on changing 
publc EntityManager appEntityManager()
{
return appEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}
to


publc EntityManager appEntityManager()
{
return SharedEntityManagerCreator.createSharedEntityManager(appEntityManagerFactory);
}   The issue got resolved. The connection is removed to the pool after the query is executed.